# SQL syntax inserting into table

Tags: mysql, sql

This line of code is no working, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with it.

INSERT INTO teacher (email,password,admin) VALUES (deborah68@example.org,d%6AsQPq7y,1);

this wont run and says the error is near the end of the line
any help is appreciated, the schema is called at3

Comment: Why are you not enclosing the string/char data in single quotes ? Assuming they are of datatype varchar, you simply enclose them in single quotes and the command will work. 

INSERT INTO teacher (email,password,admin) VALUES ('deborah68@example.org','d%6AsQPq7y',1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not enclosing the string/char data in single quotes ? Assuming they are of datatype varchar, you simply enclose them in single quotes and the command will work.

```
INSERT INTO teacher (email,password,admin) VALUES ('deborah68@example.org','d%6AsQPq7y',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your email and password are datatype of varchar, try putting '' between the values, or better you can use parameterized value if it's any backend code, try:

```
INSERT INTO teacher (email,password,admin) VALUES ('deborah68@example.org','d%6AsQPq7y',1);
```